# Laptop won't charge using USB-C hub with power delivery

Tags: usb-c, usb-hub, usb-power-delivery, lg-gram

Wondering why my laptop doesn't charge using the USB-C hub with power delivery only after reconnecting the power source to the hub.

## List of Devices:

**Laptop**
(LG Gram 15 2022 lg-15z90q-gaa56p) USB-C (Thunderbolt 4) with power delivery. Original power supply: 65W (20V - 3,25 Amp.), Type-C PD - USB-C Connector.

**HUB** (Linq) with PD function:
1 x USB-C PD (3.0) charging - up to 100W, (Note: 15W used to power the hub)
Note: other simillar hubs used but behaviour is the same (Anker and Ugreen).

**Power Supply** (used in this scenario):
UGREEN Nexode 100W - Model CD226 GaN, UGREEN 100W USB C charger supports Power Delivery 3.0
USB-C1/C2 output    5V/3A, 9V/3A, 12V/3A, 15V/3A, 20V/5A, 3.3-21V/5A; PPS Adaptive Charge 100W Max.

**Cable**
(used between Power Supply (Ugreen) <-> Hub with PD
UGREEN USB C USB C Charging Cable 100W (5A/20V) Double Angle Plug PD 3.0 QC 4.0

## Connections:

Wall plug (220v) > (Power supply) UGREEN Nexode 100W > Ugreen cable (5A/20V) > HUB (Linq) with PD function (USB-C PD 3.0) >  Laptop (LG Gram 15 2022) USB-C (Thunderbolt 4) PD

## Situation

After connection above, everything is OK and the laptop is charging.

Then I disconnect the power in ugreen cable, or disconnect power supply from wall plug.
Important Note: the Hub is not disconnected from the laptop (My primary intention is to not wear out the laptop internal port USB-C)
After this disconnection, the battery is not charging (as expected).

**Then comes the problem:
When I reconnect the power supply (between wall plug and HUB input USB-C PD)
The laptop remains in a state of not charging. That's the problem.
Even after restarting, the PC will not charge.**

I can get the laptop to start charging again if I:

- shut down and startup laptop.
- remove and reconnect the USB-C connector between hub and laptop.

While these are little workaround, none of these solutions are good or practical for me. My intention here is to just unplug and replug the USB-C connector between the power adapter (ugreen 100W) and Hub PD port input.

Could this be an issue related to the model of my laptop, BIOS configuration, Win 11 Power configs, or even a USB-C / Thunderbolt 4 incompatibility?